Is it possible to use the formula of the thrust equation for a helicopter on Venus?
I'm trying to find traction for a landing craft with a rotary system (helicopter) for takeoff and maneuvering from the surface of Venus. I do not take into account the temperature.
I use the formula thrust equation from https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/94758/87892 $T = ½ \rho (\omega R)^2 \pi R^2 C_T$
Initial data:
$Weight$= 300 $kg$,
$\rho $ = 65 $kg/m^3$,
$C_T$ = 0.028,
$Nrotors$= 1,
Suppose that: $\omega$ = 300 $rpm$ = 34.415 $rad/s$, $R$ = 1 $m$.
Now let's calculate remembering that Helicopter has 1 rotor
$T =1 \cdot ½ \cdot65(34.415\cdot1)^2 \pi 1^2 \cdot 0.028 = 3384N$
Since $g_{venus} = 8.87m/s^ 2$, the thrust is 3384/8.87=381.51 kg, which allows a helicopter weighing 300 kg to take off.
As I understand it, for the helicopter to take off and maneuver, it is necessary that the thrust be greater than the weight of the helicopter in this case 381.51 > 300 kg. But if I want to find the minimum thrust for a helicopter to take off, I need to pick up the radius of the propeller, the number of screws, the rotation speed of the helicopter propeller, the power, and then compare it with the weight of the helicopter, but I do not understand where exactly to find the rotation speed of the helicopter propeller and the radius of the helicopter propeller?
Considering that there is a high pressure on the surface of Venus - 9.2 MPa (92 bar), how does the pressure affect the aerodynamics, thrust and takeoff of the helicopter?
If you have any literature, I would appreciate it if you would share it.
Thank you.

You prescribed the rotational speed of the helicopter propeller to be 300 rpm and the radius to be 1 meter.  Not really sure what your question is. The first order effects of the pressure would be in the density term

I'm torn on the meta for this. I think it should be pretty clear to anyone with a little grounding in physics that, like tckosvic mentioned, the pressure and temperature are part of the density term.  I think it should also be clear that the thrust equation is basically a momentum-balance equation and is going to apply where you can push around gas.  But I have an answer elsewhere telling someone "no of course helicopters don't work outside the atmosphere, even though there is some matter density"...but we don't want a lot of "do helicopters work here? what about here?" Qs.

looks like there is a rotation rate (omega) and radius (R) in your thrust equation. You know your thrust requirement, pick a value for either omega or R and compute the other with the thrust equation.

Take into account that the atmosphere on the surface isn't gas, it's supercritical fluid. Had the temperature been lower, the CO2 would be liquid or solid.

A good OrderOfMagnitude method for calculating this is the momentum theory method used in this answer.

$$T = C_T \cdot \rho \cdot A \cdot \Omega^2 \cdot R^2$$
If we take $C_T$ identical to that on earth, look up $\rho$, and set the tip velocity $\Omega R $close to the local speed of sound, we have two unknowns: thrust T and disk area A. So disk area A will follow out of the weight of the device, which will be constructed on earth...

...how does the pressure affect the aerodynamics, thrust and takeoff of the helicopter?

The static pressures above and below the rotor are identical. We're concerned here with the added dynamic pressure caused by the rotor, which is a function of accelerated mass flow, as computed by the impulse theory. Which does not account for blade resistance and some other factors required to compute the driving power, but like said it is a good first-design-method.
